Setting up SSL for localhost (MacOS / rails / react / vite)
I'm trying to configure an app on my local development environment to use SSL.  I started down this path when I noticed a CORS error upon trying to request data from the back end Rails API.  When I try to access the homepage at https://localhost:3001, I receive the following message:

Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:3001. SSL received
a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.


I am also seeing the following output:
06:25:30 web.1   | 2024-09-15 06:25:30 -0400 HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>

To run the server locally I typically run bin/dev. This is the script for that:
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if gem list --no-installed --exact --silent foreman; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

# Default to port 3000 if not specified
export PORT="${PORT:-3001}"

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev --env /dev/null "$@"

What's interesting is that when I simply run rails s, I am able to access the front end at https://localhost:3000 as well return data from the API at https://localhost:3001/api/reports.  This all leads me to think that something is wrong with my Puma configuration.
So far I have done the following to try and get this to work properly:

regenerated SSL keys/certs for both rails and vite, verified that they are located under app/config/ssl
Verified that the keys are added to my keychain
modified my puma configuration to bind SSL
set my vite config to use https
installed rack-cors in the gemfile
cleared my browser cache, tried accessing localhost via a different browser or incognito mode
replaced `bin/rails server with

Gemfile:
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'

config/puma.rb:
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == "development"
  ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '3001', {
    key: "config/ssl/localhost.key",
    cert: "config/ssl/localhost.crt",
    verify_mode: "none"
  }

  puts "Puma running with SSL on https://localhost:3001"
else
  port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
  puts "Puma running on HTTP on port #{ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }}"
end

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

preload_app!

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 } if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == "production"

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

plugin :tmp_restart

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") if ENV["PIDFILE"]

Procfile.dev:
web: env RUBY_DEBUG_OPEN=true bin/rails server
vite: bin/vite dev
css: yarn build:css --watch
types: yarn ts-check

vite.config.ms:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import * as path from 'path';
import FullReload from 'vite-plugin-full-reload';
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby';
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
import fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    RubyPlugin(),
    FullReload(['config/routes.rb', 'app/views/**/*'], { delay: 250 }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@/components', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/frontend/components') },
      { find: '@/stylesheets', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/frontend/stylesheets') },
      { find: '@/entrypoints', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/javascript/entrypoints') },
    ],
  },
  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('config/ssl/localhost-vite.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('config/ssl/localhost-vite.crt'),
    },
    port: 3000, // Vite server port
  },
});

config/initializers/cors.rb:
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  Rails.logger.info "\n\n\nCORS ENABLED \n\n\n"
  allow do
    origins 'https://localhost:3001' # React app URL with HTTPS

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true
  end
end

config/environments/development.rb:
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

Rails.application.configure do
  Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
    ActiveStorage::Blob
  end

  config.enable_reloading = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.server_timing = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :raise
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  config.active_job.verbose_enqueue_logs = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.action_view.annotate_rendered_view_with_filenames = true
  config.action_controller.raise_on_missing_callback_actions = true

end


Based on your setup, it looks like your Puma configuration for SSL may be conflicting with how you're starting the server with foreman. The most likely culprit is that foreman is starting your Rails app without the SSL bindings.
